# Android Firefox ultrawide fullscreen: best fit instead fit screen?

Tags: android, firefox, fullscreen, widescreen

On a 21:9 **ultrawide** screen phone (moto g 5G plus, Android 10), while playing youtube videos in full screen, Firefox is using "*fit screen*" presentation, which touches left and right screen borders but cuts upper and lower parts of the video:
[image: "fit screen" in Firefox]

Is it possible to make it "*best fit*", where it touches the upper and lower sides of the screen and leaves black parts in the left and right sides?
[image: "best fit" viewing with jQuarks]
This last capture is from another browser (jQuarks).

Tried both the latest Firefox 85.1.1 or Firefox Beta 86.0.0-beta.2 and they both use the same "*fit screen*" indifferently if the site is viewed in **mobile** or **desktop** mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems to be a bug which is addressed in [Videos with different aspect ratio than device are zoomed in](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/8252) and the current workaround which works well is to use ublock-origin addon and add these 2 filters:

```
m.youtube.com##.html5-video-player.ytp-large-width-mode video.video-stream.html5-main-video:style(height: 100vh !important)
m.youtube.com##.html5-video-player.ytp-large-width-mode .captions-text:style(position: fixed; bottom: 1em)
```